# To maintain same format for data in a column while using it inside concatenation function

Tags: sql-server, excel, excel-formula

I'm using formula in excel to generate sql statements. I have used format cells option to make sure all the data in Zip_Codes column have 5 digits. Unfortunately, retrieving cell data using Concatenation function doesn't provide the exact format. for example:

```
         A   |   B        |       C       |
|  1  | Zip   | City       | SQL Statement |
|-----|-------|------------|---------------|
|  2  | 00501 | Holtsville |=CONCATENATION("INSERT into @table1(Zip_Code, City) values ('",A2,"','",B2,"')") |
|-----|-------|------------|---------------|
|  3  | 00601 |Adjuntas    |=CONCATENATION("INSERT into @table1(Zip_Code, City) values ('",A3,"','",B3,"')")|
```

The SQL statement I'm getting is:

```
INSERT into @table 1 (Zip_Code, City) values ('501', 'Holtsville')
INSERT into @table 1 (Zip_Code, City) values ('601', 'Adjuntas')
```

The SQL statement should be something like this:

```
INSERT into @table 1 (Zip_Code, City) values ('00501', 'Holtsville')
INSERT into @table 1 (Zip_Code, City) values ('00601', 'Adjuntas')
```

I'm finding it difficult to get those leading zeros in the Zip_Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number in column A have a custom format of `00000` but the actual value is only the three digit number.

So you need to include the formatting with TEXT()

Change `,A2,` to:

```
,TEXT(A2,"00000"),
```

So the whole Formula:

```
=CONCATENATION("INSERT into @table1(Zip_Code, City) values ('",TEXT(A2,"00000"),"','",B2,"')")
```